# SQL Query data range limit

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this where SQL Query. I want to know if I can limit that user can only pick 2 days of of date range. meaning they cannot pick 1 month or 1 week or more than 2 days difference of querty data range.

```
WHERE
    To_Date(to_char(B.time_stamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY') 
and To_Date(to_char(B.rest_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: @Michael sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that, do you want me to add Oracle tag?

Comment: yes - just confirming that it was Oracle so it could be tagged

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are just asking how to limit the two dates so that they are within 2 days of each other.  Date math is pretty simple in Oracle (which is my guess as to the DB you are using):

```
WHERE ABS(Date1 - Date2) <= 2
```

You don't need to convert it at all with to_char or anything else, since it is stored internally as an actual date. You can use this same type of logic to make sure it is less than 16 hours:

```
WHERE ABS(Date1 - Date2) <= 16/24
```

As long as you remember to adjust your units appropriately.

Note that in this case, 2 days means 48 hours. If you mean it has to be 2 actual days, then it is slightly different.

Comment: `'?DATE2::?'` and `'?DATE1::?'` is part of html meaning users picks the range via html, I don't know if that will make any difference. **edit** I tried it, I get this error, `One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended at`

Comment: I don't think I understand after all. Can you clarify your question? What are b.time_stamp and b.rest_date? And where do DATE1 and DATE2 come from? And which of those dates needs to have at most a 2 day difference?

Comment: `B.time_stamp = DATE1 ` and `B.rest_date = DATE2` `?DATE1::?` and `?DATE2::?` means user can pick from drop down menu. or if I have  `B.time_stamp = 08/10/2012` and `B.rest_date = 08/15/2012` means that is manually coded user cannot change date. so date1 and date2 gives user to pick/choose date and if not I have to manually enter into query code.